# Double splitview

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, uisplitviewcontroller

In my application i want to add multiple splitviews as like in the image, i have gone through so man
[Split1](https://github.com/jeremieweldin/JWSlideMenu),[Split2](https://github.com/devindoty/DDMenuController),[Split3](https://github.com/pkluz/PKRevealController/).

[image]

But no one supports nested splitviews.Can one please help me with some refrence.

Comment: https://github.com/gotosleep/JASidePanels please visit this link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this control or search another custom control.

[COCOA CONTROL](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/clcascade)

Updated Answer:

[NEW Control](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/stackscrollview)

Comment: NO.its so complicated.Most of them for ipad.I want for iphone

Comment: new Controler in where

Comment: Just click below the New Control

Comment: That is also for ipad only

Comment: Try this [https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/hackers-a-hacker-news-app-for-iphone] but this only for one split view.

Comment: Have you check this 2nd New Control??

Comment: try this 3rd new [https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/ghsidebarnav] & its working!!